How to unblock a user-agent on time based logic using ModSecurity
Here's the situation:

If a particular user-agent sends more than 10 requests to the domain within 5 minutes, the rule must apply a response with a code 429. For that specific agent to that specific domain.

The duration of the 429 response is 1 hour. Regardless of continued requests from the agent during that hour, it will be unblocked (code 200) after the hour elapses.

Subsequently, the process returns to point 1 and repeats.


My rule is
SecAction "id:13576460, phase:1, nolog, pass, initcol:resource=%{REQUEST_HEADERS.User-Agent}_%{REQUEST_HEADERS.Host}"

SecRule REQUEST_HEADERS:User-Agent "@contains facebookexternalhit" \
    "id:13576461,\
    phase:2,\
    t:none,\
    setvar:resource.counter=+1_%{REQUEST_HEADERS.Host},\
    expirevar:resource.counter=300_%{REQUEST_HEADERS.Host},\
    setvar:resource.blocked=+1_%{REQUEST_HEADERS.Host},\
    expirevar:resource.blocked=3600_%{REQUEST_HEADERS.Host},\
    nolog"

SecRule RESOURCE:blocked "@ge 10" \
    "id:13576462,\
    phase:2,\
    t:none,\
    deny,\
    status:429,\
    log,\
    msg:'Excessive requests from user agent'"

Unfortunately, it's only partially effective. Allow me to elaborate:

Yes, it successfully blocks after the 10th attempt within 5 minutes.
Yes, it unblocks the agent after 1 hour.
However, for the unblocking to occur, the agent must refrain from making any requests during the blocking period.

Here's the question: Is it possible to achieve unblocking regardless of whether the agent continues sending requests, focusing solely on the 1-hour criteria?
Thank you.

I would solve this with fail2ban (with ModSecurity) instead of native ModSecurity solution, but if you insists this method, try to convert your first rule into a chained rule, for eg:
SecRule REQUEST_HEADERS:User-Agent "@contains facebookexternalhit" \
    "id:13576461,\
    phase:2,\
    t:none,\
    nolog,\
    chain"
    SecRule RESOURCE:blocked "@lt 10" \
        setvar:resource.counter=+1_%{REQUEST_HEADERS.Host},\
        expirevar:resource.counter=300_%{REQUEST_HEADERS.Host},\
        setvar:resource.blocked=+1_%{REQUEST_HEADERS.Host},\
        expirevar:resource.blocked=3600_%{REQUEST_HEADERS.Host}"

This will increment the values if your condition is true (User-Agent containst facebookexternalhit) AND the resource variable is less than 10. If the value is greater or equal than 10, the value won't change (and the expirevar action won't executed again).
This is just an idea, please let me know if it works or not.
